# Return node if relationship is not present

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a query using cypher that will "Find" missing ingredients that a chef might have, My graph is set up like so:

```
(ingredient_value)-[:is_part_of]->(ingredient)
```

`(ingredient)` would have a key/value of name="dye colors".  `(ingredient_value)` could have a key/value of value="red" and "is part of" the `(ingredient, name="dye colors")`.

```
(chef)-[:has_value]->(ingredient_value)<-[:requires_value]-(recipe)-[:requires_ingredient]->(ingredient)
```

I'm using this query to get all the `ingredients`, but not their actual values, that a recipe requires, but I would like the return only the `ingredients` that the chef does not have, instead of all the ingredients each recipe requires. I tried

```
(chef)-[:has_value]->(ingredient_value)<-[:requires_value]-(recipe)-[:requires_ingredient]->(ingredient)<-[:has_ingredient*0..0]-chef
```

but this returned nothing.

Is this something that can be accomplished by cypher/neo4j or is this something that is best handled by returning all ingredients and sorted through them myself?

Bonus: Also is there a way to use cypher to match all values that a chef has to all values that a recipe requires. So far I've only returned all partial matches that are returned by a `chef-[:has_value]->ingredient_value<-[:requires_value]-recipe` and aggregating the results myself.

Comment: Check here for information relevant to v3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673223/finding-nodes-that-do-not-have-specific-relationship-cypher-neo4j

Comment: For future users; can use `exists` in a `WHERE` clause (also negate it as well), https://neo4j.com/developer/subqueries/#existential-subqueries for more information.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

**Update 01/10/2013:**

Came across this in the Neo4j **2.0** reference:

*Try not to use optional relationships.
Above all,*

***don’t use them like this:***

*`MATCH a-[r?:LOVES]->() WHERE r IS NULL` where you just make sure that they don’t exist.*

***Instead do this like so:***

```
MATCH (a) WHERE NOT (a)-[:LOVES]->()
```

---

Using cypher for checking if relationship doesn't exist:

```
...
MATCH source-[r?:someType]-target
WHERE r is null
RETURN source
```

The ? mark makes the relationship optional.

OR

In neo4j 2 do:

```
...
OPTIONAL MATCH source-[r:someType]-target
WHERE r is null
RETURN source
```

Now you can check for non-existing (null) relationship.

Comment: In Neo4j 2.0, use OPTIONAL MATCH to match optional relationships, i.e the first example would look like

    OPTIONAL MATCH (source)-[r:someType]-(target) RETURN source, r

Comment: I am trying to have a labeled node in WHERE NOT, it does not work. Like: MATCH a WHERE NOT (a)-[:LOVES]->(Stranger), in this 'Stranger' is a node label. I am using neo4j version 2.1.2

Comment: Nevermind, I understand why you'd want to show the progression to reach this answer: MATCH a WHERE NOT (a)-[:LOVES]->()

Comment: Good day to you too !

Comment: The `MATCH a...` example should now be `MATCH (a) WHERE NOT (a)-[:LOVES]->()`

Comment: @gil-stal Why I can't use node name with this query like this. MATCH a WHERE NOT (a)-[:LOVES]->(b:SomeLabel) . If I don't use node name then it works.

Answer (score 27):

For fetching nodes with not any relationship

This is the good option to check relationship is exist or not

```
MATCH (player)
    WHERE NOT(player)-[:played]->()
    RETURN player
```

You can also check multiple conditions for this
It will return all nodes, which not having "played" Or "notPlayed" Relationship.

```
MATCH (player) 
 WHERE NOT (player)-[:played|notPlayed]->()
 RETURN player
```

To fetch nodes which not having any realtionship

```
MATCH (player) 
WHERE NOT (player)-[r]-()
RETURN player
```

It will check node not having any incoming/outgoing relationship.

Comment: `MATCH (player) 
WHERE NOT (player)-[r]-()
RETURN player`  gives **Variable r not defined** error. How can i define r?

Comment: to fix this, either specify a relationship (e.g. `(player -[:rel]- ()`) or leave empty for any relation `(player -[]- ()`

Comment: `MATCH (player) 
WHERE NOT (player)-[]-()
RETURN player` - It works fine

Comment: Your first query is actually wrong. The MATCH pattern itself always returns only existing relationships, with none of them NULL. So your WHERE line has nothing to filter from.

Comment: @CristiS. Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the query it should work

Answer (score 8):

If you need "conditional exclude" semantic, you can achieve it this way.

As of neo4j 2.2.1, you can use `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause and filter out the unmatched(`NULL`) nodes.

It is also important to use `WITH` clause between the `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses, so that the first `WHERE` defines a condition for the optional match and the second `WHERE` behaves like a filter.

Assuming we have 2 types of nodes: `Person` and `Communication`. If I want to get all Persons which have never communicated by the telephone, but may have communicated other ways, I would make this query:

```
MATCH (p: Person) 
OPTIONAL MATCH p--(c: Communication) 
WHERE c.way = 'telephone'
WITH p, c 
WHERE c IS NULL 
RETURN p
```

The match pattern will match all Persons with their communications where `c` will be `NULL` for non-telephone Communications. Then the filter(`WHERE` after `WITH`) will filter out telephone Communications leaving all others.

References:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html#_introduction_3
http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-neo4j-optional

Comment: Pretty sure you need parens around the p in line 2, like OPTIONAL MATCH (p)--(c: Communication)

Comment: @GuidoInLFP I don't know about the current version, but in the version specified you didn't need to.

Answer (score 2):

The last query should be:

```
START chef = node(..)
MATCH (chef)-[:has_value]->(ingredient_value)<-[:requires_value]-(recipe)-[:requires_ingredient]->(ingredient)
WHERE (ingredient)<-[:has_ingredient]-chef
RETURN ingredient
```

This pattern: `(ingredient)<-[:has_ingredient*0..0]-chef`

Is the reason it didn't return anything. `*0..0` means that the length of the relationships must be zero, which means that ingredient and chef must be the same node, which they are not.

Comment: Yes, but it does not return the desired ingredient. It returns what the chef already has in common with the recipe, I want to find out the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a gist showing how this can be done quite naturally using Cypher 2.0

http://gist.neo4j.org/?9171581

The key point is to use optional match to available ingredients and then compare to filter for missing (null) ingredients or ingredients with the wrong value.

Note that the notion is declarative and doesn't need to describe an algorithm, you just write down what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I completed this task using gremlin. I did

```
x=[]

g.idx('Chef')[[name:'chef1']].as('chef')
.out('has_ingredient').as('alreadyHas').aggregate(x).back('chef')
.out('has_value').as('values')
.in('requires_value').as('recipes')
.out('requires_ingredient').as('ingredients').except(x).path()
```

This returned the paths of all the missing ingredients. I was unable to formulate this in the cypher language, at least for version 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

For new versions of Neo4j, you'll have this error:

```
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE NOT (:Chef)-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]->(ingredient)
RETURN * LIMIT 100;
```

> This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
> Coercion of list to boolean is deprecated. Please consider using `NOT isEmpty(...)` instead.

To fix it:

```
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((:Chef)-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]->(ingredient))
RETURN * LIMIT 100;
```