# Finding nodes that do not have specific relationship (Cypher/neo4j)

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j db with the following:

```
a:Foo
b:Bar
```

about 10% of db have `(a)-[:has]->(b)`

I need to get only the nodes that do NOT have that relationship!

previously doing `()-[r?]-()` would've been perfect! However it is no longer supported :( instead, doing as they suggest a

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Foo)-[r:has]->(b:Bar) WHERE b is NULL RETURN a
```

gives me a null result since optional match needs BOTH nodes to either be there or BOTH nodes not to be there...

So how do i get all the `a:Foo` nodes that are NOT attached to `b:Bar`?

Note: dataset is millions of nodes so the query needs to be efficient or otherwise it times out.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That would be

```
MATCH (a:Foo) WHERE not ((a)-[:has]->(:Bar)) RETURN a;
```

Comment: Holy smokes... this is it! i kept trying to put the label in the right side of that match.

Comment: Doesn't it have any performance problems? It seems to take aaaaaaall nodes

Answer (score 12):

This also works if you're looking for all singletons/orphans:

```
MATCH (a:Foo) WHERE not ((a)--()) RETURN a;
```