# neo4j finding nodes without specific PARAMETERIZED relationship (path)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673223/finding-nodes-that-do-not-have-specific-relationship-cypher-neo4j), but with relationship parameters using comparison operators.

```
MATCH (a:Foo) WHERE not ((a)-[:has]->(:Bar)) RETURN a;
```

I can add inline parameterized equality comparisons, such as:

```
MATCH (a:Foo) WHERE not ((a)-[:has {this: 'works'}]->(:Bar)) RETURN a;
```

But not >=, <=, etc. Best explanation for usecase would be if [:has] has a property effectiveEndDate and I want to return (a:foo) that doesn't have ANY active relationships, per the effectiveEndDate property on the relationship.

EDIT for clarification:

The best way to do this is to match on all ACTIVE relationships (per :has.effectiveEndDate)... so inactive/expired don't match and don't play a role here, and then NOT those active relationships. So the (a:foo) returned are only ones that are NOT active.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question, but you can use a `WHERE` clause for inequality comparisons:

```
MATCH (a:Foo)-[r:has]->(b:Bar)
WHERE r.effectiveEndData <= timestamp()
RETURN a,b
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought... not exactly. See edit above.