# Cypher - Return node if relationship not present with node of particular label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please see similar answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14254214/1060044

I have a requirement where I have pattern like below:

```
MATCH (b:Label1{id:123})<--(Label2)<--(a:Label3) WHERE NOT (a)<--(Label4) return a;
```

I am getting syntax error with this query. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

I am using neo4j community version 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using labels in Cypher, you always have to use a colon `:` in front of them:

```
MATCH (b:Label1{id:123})<--(:Label2)<--(a:Label3) WHERE NOT (a)<--(:Label4) return a;
```

So from node 123 having label `Label1` you follow a incoming relationship to a node with label `Label2`, to node a with label `Label3` and you make sure that a is not connection with any node node labelled `Label4`.