# How can I upgrade Neo4j 2.2.0 to 2.2.1?

Tags: neo4j

Even after following the advice in one of the comments here ([Create on NOT MATCH command for Neo4j's CQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873015/create-on-not-match-command-for-neo4js-cql)) to set allow_store_upgrade to true in conf/neo4j.properties, I was not able to successfully upgrade to 2.2.1

The documentation does not explain how to here either: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/deployment-upgrading.html

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: What do you mean by I was not able to upgrade ? Is the database not starting, any messages.log you can share ? Normally you should just copy your graph.db folder into the new 2.2.1

Comment: I see no evidence in localhost:7474 or in the console.log that it upgrade to 2.2.1. Which log are you talking about?

Comment: so your 2.2.1 database is running ? The $neo4j_home/data/graph.db/messages.log file

Comment: I'm not seeing any occurrences of 2.2.1 in the messages.log file

Comment: did you moved the store files to the new neo4j 2.2.1 directory. If yes it is sufficient. allow_store_upgrade is for non-automatic store upgrades. 2.2.0 -> 2.2.1 is safe automatic store upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this just now in the other thread, but it's good to have it out there so people can search for it.  Whenever you upgrade an instance of Neo4j you need to:

- Download the new version
- Copy the `data/graph.db` folder from the old location to the new location (make sure all servers are shut down first)
- Set `allow_store_upgrade` to `true` in the new instance
- Start up the server (at start up, the data in the `data/graph.db` folder will be updated to the format required for the new version