# Cypher - neo4j find recursive end nodes

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to find all *beginning nodes* for a given node type, starting with any node in my database. These are nodes that have no relationships pointing to them.

I'm currently doing it manually, but need a recursive-type of statement to simplify and expand. Here is what I have so far, with a return statement describing what I need.

```
MATCH ((d1:Type1 {Name: "test1"}))
MATCH ((t1:Type2)-[:Rel1]->(h1:Type3))
MATCH ((d1)<-[ud1:Rel3]-(t1))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((h1)<-[:Rel1]-(t2:Type2))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((t2)<-[:Rel2]-(d2:Type1))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((d2)<-[ud2:Rel3]-(t3:Type2))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((t3)-[:Rel1]->(h2:Type3))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((h2)<-[:Rel1]-(t4:Type2))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((t4)<-[:Rel2]-(d3:Type1))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((d3)<-[ud3:Rel3]-(t5:Type2))

RETURN DISTINCT Type1.Name where there is no Rel3 relationship
```

The ask here is to navigate the recursive

```
Type1 < -  Type2 -> Type3 <- Type2 < - Type1 < - Type2 -> Type3 <- Type2
```

path, until there are no Type2s pointing to the Type1, and return the names of these Type1s.

Comment: So you want to return all Type1 nodes that don't have a Rel3 relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Your query example is quite complex and contains stand-in types that make it a bit hard to understand.

I think this boils down to something quite simple, you should try this:

```
MATCH (startingPoint:Type1 { name: "test1" })
MATCH (startingPoint)-[:relType*]->(headNode)
OPTIONAL MATCH (headNode)-[f:relType]->()
WHERE f is null;
```

So all this does is match from a `startingPoint` through any number of relationships to a `headNode`.  How do we know that the `headNode` is really at the beginning?   Because we insist with the `OPTIONAL MATCH` that it cannot be connected to anything else further upstream.  We attempt to match what *would be* another upstream match, and then insist with the `WHERE` clause that it must be missing, hence `headNode` is really "at the top".

Customize this with your own `relTypes` and labels, and you should be able to follow this pattern.

More broadly, when you're asking about a beginning node and it *not having* some relationships, [See also this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952332/cypher-return-node-if-relationship-is-not-present).

Comment: This is a great answer assuming there isn't a "middle" object in the model. I'm not sure if cypher has the syntax yet to handle this type of recursive multi-relationship traversal. See my answer for the workaround, as it just requires an additional create statement, then your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[FrobberOfBits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30139659/4879749) has a great answer, but doesn't address the need to navigate through mutiple nodes types recursively. I've still yet to see a syntax that allows for this type of recursive querying in Cypher.

The work around is to simply create a new relationship using the complex traversal, then use FrobberOfBits solution to find the headnode.

Here is what I came up with:

```
MATCH ((d1:Type1))
MATCH ((q1:Type2)-[:Rel1]->(p1:Type3))
MATCH ((d1)<-[ud1:Rel2]-(q1))
MATCH ((p1)<-[:Rel1]-(q2:Type2))
MATCH ((q2)<-[:Rel3]-(d2:Type1))
WITH  distinct d1 as child,d2 as parent
CREATE (child)<-[:ParentOf]-(parent)
```

This creates a new relationship type between two Type1s, removing the need to navigate through the different node types recursively, and simply allowing tree-traversal on a single node type (As FrobberOfBits masterfully explained)

Here is my resulting query using the types in the question and the above create statement, with an alternate syntax to Fibber's.

```
MATCH((d1:Type1 {Name: "test1"}))
OPTIONAL MATCH ((d1)<-[r1:Rel1*]-(d2:Type1))
WHERE NOT (d2)<--()
return distinct d2.Name
```

Sorry for the poor type masking! I should have been more creative with my aliasing.