# Cypher Query not returning nonexistent relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph database where there are user and interest nodes which are connected by **IS_INTERESTED** relationship. I want to find interests which are not selected by a user. I wrote this query and it is not working

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (u:User{userId : 1})-[r:IS_INTERESTED] -(i:Interest)
WHERE r is NULL
Return i.name as interest
```

According to answers to similar questions on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952332/cypher-return-node-if-relationship-is-not-present#) one), the above query is supposed to work.However,in this case it returns null. But when running the following query it works as expected:

```
MATCH (u:User{userId : 1}), (i:Interest)
WHERE NOT (u) -[:IS_INTERESTED] -(i)
return i.name as interest
```

The reason I don't want to run the above query is because Neo4j gives a warning:

> **This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.**
>
> If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this
>   will build a cartesian product between all those parts. This may
>   produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing. While
>   occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate the
>   query that avoids the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a
>   relationship between the different parts or by using OPTIONAL MATCH
>   (identifier is: (i))

What am I doing wrong in the first query where I use *OPTIONAL MATCH* to find nonexistent relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `MATCH` is looking for the pattern as a whole, and if can not find it in its entirety - does not return anything.

2) I think that this query will be effective:

```
// Take all user interests
MATCH (u:User{userId: 1})-[r:IS_INTERESTED]-(i:Interest)
    WITH collect(i) as interests
    // Check what interests are not included
    MATCH (ni:Interest) WHERE NOT ni IN interests
RETURN ni.name
```

Answer (score 1):

When your `OPTIONAL MATCH` query does not find a match, then both `r` AND `i` must be `NULL`. After all, since there is no relationship, there is no way get the nodes that it points to.

Comment: I see. So is there a better way (than using the second query I used) to find interests not selected by a specific user?

Comment: I do not see a better way.

Answer (score 0):

A WHERE directly after the OPTIONAL MATCH is *pulled into* the evaluation.

If you want to post-filter you have to use a WITH in between.

```
MATCH (u:User{userId : 1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:IS_INTERESTED] -(i:Interest)
WITH r,i
WHERE r is NULL
Return i.name as interest
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it doesn't return anything. It just returns the message _(no changes, no rows)_